# Retornar uma variável (Singleton) usando Node que depende de Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises, singleton

Boa tarde galera,

Tem como criar uma variável no NodeJS/JS em que eu retornaria um valor somente para ser usado diversas vezes ao longo do programa?

Exemplificando meu problema:
Tenho que fazer login em uma plataforma para depois enviar dados para ela. Ao fazer login, ela me retorna uma "chave" que com ela eu poderei fazer o envio dos dados.

Terei que realizar o envio de dados diversas vezes e o login sempre será o mesmo, com base nisso, seria possível ter uma variável que receberá da função que faz o login somente a chave?

O código que eu tentei inicialmente não utilizava promises como pode ser visto abaixo:

```
var retornaToken = restclient.post(url, args, function (data, res) {
        if(res.statusCode === 200){
            console.log("Conectou com sucesso");
            return data.chave;
        } else {
            console.log("Opa, não conectou");
            return false;
        }
});

module.exports = {
    retornaToken : retornaToken
};
```

porem, em outra classe ao chamar a retornaToken, o retorno que tenho é o ClientRequest e não o token.

Então comecei a utilizar promises usando o package `Q` do node, entretanto, continuo com problema.

Já criei uma função para realizar o login usando promises

```
function realizaLogin(user, pass) {
    var defer = q.defer();

    var args = {
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        data: {username: user, password: pass}
    };

    restclient.post(url, args, function (data, res) {
        if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
            console.log("Opa, deu ruim");
            defer.reject("Deu ruim!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Conectou com sucesso");
            defer.resolve(data);
        }
        //console.log("Tudo OK!\n");
        //console.log(data.access_token);    
    });
    return defer.promise; 
}

var login = realizaLogin(user, pass);

module.exports = { login : login };
```

Mas quando tentei chamar o `login` (que é exportado) da seguinte maneira

```
var login = require('./controller');

var token = login.login; // ou var token = login;

console.log(token);
```

obtenho o seguinte retorno no console:

```
{ state: 'pending' }
Conectou com sucesso
```

Já tentei usar o `Q.all` para poder vê se o mesmo espera realizar o login, criando uma outra classe e transformando o realizaLogin em um array de promises mas sem sucesso também.

Alguém sabe algum jeito de exportar somente a chave para evitar ter que fazer login a cada vez que eu tiver que enviar dados para o servidor?

Comment: por que só não guardar o token numa variável?

Comment: é exatamente isso que quero rsrsrs. O problema tá em aguardar a requisição para poder retornar esta variável que terá o token.

Comment: cria uma variável fora do callback, como por exemplo no escopo global `var token`, daí dentro do calback você atribui o valor p essa variavel `token=data.chave`.

Comment: sim, já fiz isso também, o problema é que o JS não espera o final da conclusão da função `realizaLogin` para poder retornar o valor correto, ele sempre acaba retornando null, ou string vazia.